# Securing an Azure .asmx web service for Android and iOS apps

Tags: android, ios, wcf, mobile, azure

I'm developing a standard Azure .NET cloud service with a sql backend. The sql db holds various bits of information including username and password details. I've a .NET app that communicates with Azure using message encryption over WCF using a custom username/password validator. Also I've got two mobile apps written for Android and iOS which currently use some web services I've defined in an small .asmx file (legacy code to enable the mobile apps to easily call the API). I was wanting to add authentication into the mobile apps, but am slowly sinking under the weight of information :)

I had thought Azure mobile services were the way to go (meaning I would have to rewrite the .asmx file using custom API presumably) but this only seems to offer authentication against identity providers like Google, Facebook etc. Ideally I'd want to use our sql backend as an identity provider, but have read various articles saying this is very tricky to do. In fact one article suggested using a commercial solution called Auth0.

I'm not averse to commercial solutions, but really just wondered what the simplest approach to this should be. Azure mobile services or something else?

Any help steering me in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can do "custom" authentication using your own database as the identity provider if you want to but as noted it does require a bit of work (at least more than just turning on Facebook / Twitter / etc).  I have two articles that explain how to set up custom auth using Mobile Services here:
http://chrisrisner.com/Authentication-with-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services
http://chrisrisner.com/Custom-Authentication-with-Azure-Mobile-Services-and-PikShare

The second link provides information on simplifying the scripts involved as well as using the custom API functionality of Mobile Services to handle registration / logging in.  For the most part these scripts can be dropped into your mobile service.  However, since you have an existing database you'll want to connect your Mobile Service to, you may run into issues making sure the table structures match up with what Mobile Services expect.  You may need to massage your schema / create a table specifically for your Mobile Service with the necessary user information if adding the existing table doesn't work right away.